# migrate command in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

## articles table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('Articles');
    }
```

## tags table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('article_tag',function (Blueprint $table)
        {

            $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->
                on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->
                on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

### i want to make tags table in phpmyadmin fut faced to this error after php artisan migrate command

### error

`$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_04_01_195718_create_articles_table

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'articles' already exists (SQL: create table `Articles` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment prim
ary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null, `title` varchar(255) not null, `body` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_un
icode_ci')`

Comment: Clear the migrations table. and then run "php artisan migrate" command and show the error if any.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for **user_id** table

```
Schema::create('Articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('body');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: when i use php artisan migrate just articles table made but users and tags talble dont made

Comment: i did it but my table which name is tags dont make yet

Answer (score 0):

Use To Migrate All Tables

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

If you don't want to loss your another tables data

Just goto mysql or phpmyadmin then delete the table and also from migrations

then re-run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('article_tag',function (Blueprint $table)
        {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->
                on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->
                on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```